# CSS - Child height relative to viewport if parent has position:fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I need to make the child height relative to the viewport. Using HTML:

```
<div class="parent">My divider
  <div class="child">
      Inside the div
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.t1 {
    background:#f00;
    color:#fff;
}

.t2 {
  background:#212121;
  height:100vh;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hr8sL/7646/

As you can see from the example, There's always this small gap, because it takes into account the overall height of the parent. However, I only need the child to fill "the rest" of the viewport from parent.

How should I proceed? I've tried many other things, but without sufficient result

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to remove the small gap **between** `t1` and `t2`? Can you not just give `t2` a negative `margin-top`? Or are you asking how to make `t2` take up `100%` of the **remaining** height? That would be done with `calc()`.

Comment: I don't see `position:fixed` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hr8sL/7651/).

Using the css `calc()` function we can calculate the remaining height.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* This is used to reset any browser-default margins */
}

.t1 {
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
}

.t2 {
  background: #212121;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="t1">
  My divider
</div>
<div class="t2">
  Inside the div
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify where `20px` came from?

Comment: @KoshVery I added it. OP did not specify any limitations to a set height for the "divider" and he asked for guidance.